# What are the differences between sudo and the use of groups?

Tags: security, sudo, group, privileges

I know these are  tools used for improving security. But what I would like to know is what they are and how they work?

Comment: I recommended you read `sudoers(5)` and some tutorials about `effective users/groups`  , sudoers is 3dr party package , i prefer start from here : http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialManagingGroups.html

Comment: Have you taken a look at the documentation for `sudo` yet? I'd start w/ that first. Unix groups are fairly straight-forward, and should work, conceptually, exactly how one would imagine. If you're hung up on some of the documentation for `sudo` then I'd re-target this Q around those particular points. Start docs for sudo/sudoers: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers. There are many good tutorials and guides. Here's also an intro to sudo: https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/306766:linux-101-introduction-to-sudo.

Comment: @slm There's quite a way to go from how groups work, to understanding what you can do with them to define a security policy.

Comment: @Gilles - agreed, I was merely trying to help the OP get the ball rolling with understanding things by offering  him a place to start. Since with no background at all, it's going to be difficult to understand the differences.

Answer (score 0):

In short, Sudo allows privilege escalation, while a user's groups allow access to things owned by the group.